# An error has occurred. See error log for more details. com/sap/mw/jco3/eclipse/Registry

Tags: javascript, eclipse, registry, sap-bw

Attempting to open SAP HANA BW in Eclipse IDE 09-21 application. The following error occurs: An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
com/sap/mw/jco3/eclipse/Registry

There are several unhandled loop exceptions in org.eclipse.ui. I attempted to paste the code but received an error when I pasted the code in the body.

Any feedback to resolve this error is appreciated.

Comment: You will have to show us some of the log before we can help. Show us the first log entries starting at a `!SESSION` line